# Replacing a string while choosing the order in which the part of strings get replaced first

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a string with certain words, but I also want to replace it in order of the position in the array. For example, I want to replace "b c", before I try to replace "a b", without changing the position in the original string. By the way, the letters are suppose to represent actual words, and they are not supposed be part of another word. For example, the word "sun" is part of "sunflower", and the word "sunflower" cannot be replaced just because the word "sun" is in it.

```
$text = "a b c";
$replacement = array("a b" => "ab","b c" => "bc");
$search = array_map(function($v){
    return preg_quote($v, "/");
}, array_keys($replacement));

echo $text = preg_replace_callback("/\b(" . implode("|", $search) . ")\b/", function($m)use($replacement){
    return $replacement[$m[1]];
}, $text);
```

**First Result**

```
ab c
```

**Second Result**

I switched the position in the array around, thinking that it would affect the order of which the strings get replaced. Sadly, it doesn't work like that, and I got the same result.

```
$replacement = array("b c" => "bc","a b" => "ab");
ab c
```

At this point, I realize that it wasn't the position of the array that affects which part of the string that get replaced first, but the order of the part of strings that shows up on the original string that determines the order in which it is replaced by.

So, my question is, is there a way to somehow make it so that it can replace the string in order according to the order in which it is in the array, or in a different way? For example, I want to replace

```
"b c"
```

before I try to replace "a b" without changing the position of the original string. Is that doable? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you will have to change the regex: add a negative look-ahead `a b(?! c\b)`. See [demo](http://ideone.com/SIA8ES).

Comment: @stribizhev Is this the only part of the code you've changed? $replacement = array("a b(?! c\b)" => "ab","b c" => "bc"); Please explain your negative look-ahead in an answer below, and how it works.

Comment: I only post when I am sure it is the right way of solving the issue. The negative look-ahead is making sure there is no specified pattern after the preceding subpattern match. `a b(?! c\b)` will never match `a b` followed by a space followed by a whole word `c`. Now, the question is, can this solution be extrapolated to your problem? How many possible contexts there are, how big is the replacement array? If you create it manually, then perhaps, it is a solution.

Comment: @stribizhev honestly I am a bit confused about your approach. Perhaps if you provide an answer with more details, i'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT]

The idea consists to cast the original text to an array (with one element at the beginning, the text). Array items at even index are splitted for each patterns. Since `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option is used, delimiters have always an odd index and stay untouched once they are matched.

```
$text = 'a b c';
$rep = ['b c'=>'bc', 'a b'=>'ab', ];

$pats = array_map(function($i) {
    return '~\b(' . preg_quote($i, '~') . ')\b~';
}, array_keys($rep));

$parts = (array)$text; // or $parts = [ $text ]; // it's the same

foreach ($pats as $pat) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach ($parts as $k=>$part) {
        if ($k & 1)
            $temp[] = $part;
        else
            $temp = array_merge(
                $temp,
                preg_split($pat, $part, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
            );
    }
    $parts = $temp;
}

$result = '';
foreach ($parts as $k=>$part) {
    $result .= ($k & 1) ? $rep[$part] : $part;
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Pedro answered first, sorry. But I up voted your answer!

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte's code is better and simple. It should be accepted as the best answer.

Comment: @PedroPinheiro Well. Okay. Sure. If that's what you want.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work the way the original code was wrote to work in. For example, if you put a=>b, and then b=>c, a would turn into c, instead of stopping at b. Which the original code make sure that wouldn't' happen.

Comment: @frosty: indeed, It allows circular replacements, (in the same way of `str_replace`), I didn't know it was a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @frosty: Not with this approach.

Comment: Can you think of any other way at the moment?

Comment: @frosty: perhaps something using `preg_split` to exclude parts already matched (odd items) but it's not easy.

Comment: would be nice if it was. I hope someone can figure it out.

Comment: Got to admit. This is perfection at its best.

Comment: @frosty: Thanks, but even if it works, I think there is probably a better algorithm to do that.

Comment: @frosty: perhaps a recursive approach.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code to represent what (I think) you wanted:

```
$text = "a b c a b";
$replacement = array("b c" => "bc", "a b" => "ab");
$search = array_map(function($v){
    return preg_quote($v, "/");
}, array_keys($replacement));

for($i = 0; $i < count($replacement); $i++) {
    $regex = "/\b(" . $search[$i] . ")\b/";
    echo $text = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m)use($replacement){
        return $replacement[$m[1]];
    }, $text);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Basically, instead of relying on the regex to do that work I do a for loop to go through each replacement and create the regex. That way the order of the array matters. I also changed the initial `$text` to test if it worked

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work the way the original code was wrote to work in. For example, if you put a=>b, and then b=>c, a would turn into c, instead of stopping at b. Which the original code make sure that wouldn't' happen. Same problem with Casimir's code.